# Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ real matrix not similar to any upper-triangular matrix on $\Bbb R$, prove $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix on $\Bbb C$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, similar-matrices

> Suppose a $3 \times 3$ real matrix $A$ is not similar to any upper-triangular matrix on the real field $\mathbb{R}$, that is, there is no $3 \times 3$ invertible real matrix $P$, such
>   that $P^{-1}AP$ is an upper-triangular matrix. Prove that $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix on the complex field $\mathbb{C}$.

**My Solution**

I need to cite the following result:

> Two real matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar on $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are similar on $\mathbb{R}$. In detail, if there exists an invertible $P \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ such that $B = P^{-1}AP$, then there exists a $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $B = Q^{-1}AQ$.

I then prove the conclusion by contradiction. If $A$ is not similar to a diagonal matrix on $\mathbb{C}$, $A$ would have at least two identical eigenvalues. Because $n = 3$ and the imaginary roots appear in pair, this means all $A$'s eigenvalues are real numbers. There are two cases.

- All eigenvalues equal to $\lambda_0$. Using the Jordan canonical form theory, $A$ is similar to one of the following three matrices:
      \begin{equation*}
          \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda_0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & \lambda_0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & \lambda_0
          \end{pmatrix}, \quad
          \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
          0 & \lambda_0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & \lambda_0
          \end{pmatrix}, \quad
          \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
          0 & \lambda_0 & 1 \\
          0 & 0 & \lambda_0
          \end{pmatrix}.
      \end{equation*}
  In either case, $A$ would be similar to an upper-triangular matrix on $\mathbb{R}$ (using the result stated at the very beginning), contradiction.
- Two eigenvalues equal to $\lambda_1$, the remaining eigenvalue equals to $\lambda_2 \neq \lambda_1$. Under this case, $A$ is similar to one of the following two matrices:
      \begin{equation*}
          \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & \lambda_1 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & \lambda_2
          \end{pmatrix}, \quad
          \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda_1 & 1 & 0 \\
          0 & \lambda_1 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & \lambda_2
          \end{pmatrix}.
      \end{equation*}
  In either case, $A$ would be similar to an upper-triangular matrix on $\mathbb{R}$, contradiction.

Therefore, $A$ has three different eigenvalues, hence it's diagonalizable on $\mathbb{C}$.

**My Question**

Is there any more direct solution that possibly avoids using Jordan form and the result I cited? Because this is an exercise appeared before the Jordan form chapter is introduced.

Comment: well, what results do you have that real characteristic values imply triangular form?

Comment: You did not say it. You don't want to use Jordan form. I am looking in my books for a result with less machinery, along these lines: a real square matrix with all eigenvalues real is similar to an upper triangular matrix. If true, that solves your problem. I'm looking in the first Horn and Johnson book. There is a complex version called Schur's unitary triangularization theorem. Alright, at the end of the proof they say with real matrix and all real eigenvalues, the same proof works!

Comment: Thanks, I can try if I can prove your result.

Comment: On pages 79-80 in Horn and Johnson. Proof by algorithm; the same algorithm can be carried out in real arithmetic. https://www.math.drexel.edu/~foucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect1.pdf   and many other lecture notes by different professors

Comment: Thecase of all real eigenvalues:  Proof in one page https://www.math.uh.edu/~wagner/2331/Schurs_theorem.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Great, I think I got it by induction. Your comment is very helpful.

Comment: Note that in principle there is little difference between using the real Jordan form versus the real Schur decomposition.

Comment: @copper.hat I think to prove Jordan form is much much more technical than Schur theorem. My point is to get things done using less machinenary.

Answer (score 3):

$A$ must have an eigenvalue with a non zero imaginary part (otherwise all eigenvalues are real and hence would be similar to an upper triangular matrix, cf. the real Schur form).

Since $A$ is real the non real eigenvalues must be a complex conjugate pair. Since all the eigenvalues are distinct it is diagonalisable (over $\mathbb{C}$).